# communication with stagewebview

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

i am using StageWebView for displaying the html contents in my flex application,since i have to display another application( which was developed in html5 ) in my flex application.now i need to get the values from stagewebview's html content. but i searched a lot and i couldn't be able to find the solution.even in Adobe's documentation itself , it is stated that we cant communicate over stagewebview. but i have to communicate with it.My application is flex mobile application for ios.

please suggest me on this issue.

thanks in advance
vengatesh

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for this:
http://code.google.com/p/stagewebviewbridge/

For me it is not working for some reason (compiler error) but maybe it can help you.

Comment: i also tried, but i myself also got the same error as u had got.

Comment: I have fixed the error already by importing the "src" directory of the contents of the zip into the project. It is working now but there are still some issues with a Mobile AS3 Project in Flash Builder. See also issue #25 and issue #26 at http://code.google.com/p/stagewebviewbridge/issues/list I added to the buglist. I also added a modified version with that fixes the issues of StageWebViewBridge.as that you can download if you like.